# Reverting a VertIO driver installation on boot drive

Tags: windows-10, drivers, virtual-machine, linux-kvm

I setup A VM in unRAID which utilises KVM. I passed through my physical drive which already has a installation of Windows 10.

When I passed the drive through I installed the VertIO drivers, although I can't boot into that instance of Windows using bare metal anymore. When I boot metal again I get the error INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE.

How would I go back to how it was without loosing anything?

Preferably I would like to be able to use my drive for both bare metal and a VM.

Thanks,
Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by attempting to load the drive bare metal and when Windows got to the repair stage I took these steps:

1. Select troubleshoot.
2. Advanced Options.
3. Startup Settings.
4. Options 6 "Disable Driver signature enforcement".

(Though I don't think the following steps were needed) When the system restarted I was able to login and all I had to do then was open CMD via (Windows key + R) and type CMD click ok and enter the following commands:

1. "bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot".
2. "shutdown /r /t 0".

And it was running like normal.

Comment: Strange I thought I did.